# Dell Latitude E4310 laptop does not load win7 OS after upgrading RAM

Tags: upgrade

I have Dell Latitude E4310 laptop which has two memory slots, populated with two 2 GB SoDIMMs. I have recently bought a 4 GB (1600MHz, Transcend) SoDIMM to upgrade. (Replacing one of the 2GiB modules with a 4GiB modules). I have placed it properly and even the BIOS is showing that one slot has 2GB ram and other slot has 4GB RAM.

Problem: When I turn the laptop on with the new SoDIMM in place it POSTs and then gets stuck on a black screen with a blinking cursor.
Steps Tried.

Tried the new RAM in both the slots. No change.

Comment: If you use the old RAM, does the system boot up again?

Comment: yes peter, when i place back my old ram it does boot up and work normal. Kindly help me. Even the laptop has a capacity of 8 GB RAM,
Config: Win 7, i5 processor 64bit

Comment: If you only use the new RAM, does the system still boot up?

Comment: No, but it detects that the system has a new RAM in BIOS.

Comment: We're getting closer. Now, what does "the system is not booting up" mean, exactly?

Comment: It does not load windows 7 OS. FYI- I have One 4GB Trancend Ram and one is of different company. However both the 2GB ram which was placed earlier is of same company. I m not sure if this is an issue or what?

Comment: "It does not load windows 7 OS." Please be more specific. Is there a black screen after the BIOS is done? Is the OS stuck on the loading screen? Is there an error message? Is the screen black with a blinking white text cursor? Does Windows crash?

Comment: yes,the screen goes black with a blinking white text cursor

Comment: Now that the problem is well defined, I don't have a good answer. The behavior is as if the RAM stick is not supported. I checked the manual at ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_latitude_laptop/latitude-e4310_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf, and your motherboard does indeed support 4 GB sticks. My guess is defective RAM, or maybe the 4 GB support was only added with a later firmware update, or it was botched with a firmware update?

Comment: The transcend 4GB ram which i have is 1600 Mhz..may be this is an issue. I should go for 1066Mhz as per the specification which you shared. Correct me if I am wrong and Much appreciated for your valuable time. Thanks a TON.

Comment: That would be too easy :) Higher MHz or different manufacturer should not be an issue at all. ECC should also work on non-ECC slots, and 1.35V (sometimes known as DDR3L) RAM will work in 1.5V slots (but not the other way around).

Comment: Recap: You changed some hardware and the system still powers up and goes though POST. It then gets stuck at black screen.

Possible causes: It is trying to boot from the wrong device. (quite possible if you changed BIOS settings).

Question1: Did you change any BIOS settings.  Does it boot if you go back to the original SoDIMMs?

Question2: Did you try booting with only the 4GiB SoDIMM (to prevent timing errors when the system tries to use dual channel access).

Comment: Do i need to modify some settings in BIOS...i m too frustrated. Waste of money totally.

Comment: Try a Linux LiveCD or USB with Memtestx86 on it. Run the memtest with only your new RAM for a few hours and see if that gives you anything. Tip: use Unetbootin to create your USB. Memtest86+ has its own livecd. See their site.

Comment: It is not mentioned specifically, so:
Is it a x64 Win7 or a x32?
I had troubles booting a x32 Win7 with 4 GB RAM, altough it booted fine on XP.
I guess Microsoft decided to forcefully shift users to x64, which is quite late looking at operating system history.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try with a generic troubleshooting guide, because different people might find this question. The guide is meant as a starting point. Feel free to add to it in comments, or to post a copied and improved list as your own answer:

1. Make sure the PC doesn't boot at all, and stops immediately after the BIOS. If you see the Windows logo, this is not a RAM issue.
2. Make sure the PC still works normally if you change the RAM back to the previous configuration. If it doesn't, something else changed (fat finger inputs in the BIOS?), and that other change is the problem.
3. Make sure the capacity of your RAM stick is supported by your motherboard. [In this case, 1, 2, and 4 GB are supported](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_latitude_laptop/latitude-e4310_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf).
4. Make sure the new RAM is rated at the same or higher frequency (MHz) than what the machine specifies. If it isn't, you have the wrong RAM. [In this case, the machine requires 1066 MHz or higher](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_latitude_laptop/latitude-e4310_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf).
5. Check the Voltage. 1.5V RAM won't work in a 1.35V slot. on the other hand, 1.35V RAM will work in a 1.5V slot. Sometimes 1.35V is only specified as DDR3L. This advice applies only to DDR3 RAM.
6. Use only one stick at a time to figure out exactly which sticks work and which sticks don't. Sometimes all sticks are fine but a specific slot on the motherboard is broken.
7. If you have the option, test the RAM in a different machine. If it doesn't work it's probably broken.
8. Apply all available firmware updates to the motherboard. In this case, [a BIOS update is available](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=7DP7H).
9. This one I'm guessing, it's posible that this problem doesn't exist: A BIOS setting may try to force RAM to 1.35V or to use ECC and prevent the fallback to 1.5V or to non-ECC. If so, disable these options.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I will try to update the BIOS and will get back to you.

Comment: I have updated my BIOS from A03 to A07 however still RAM is not working. I can see that the new RAM is 1.5V. However not sure about my memory slot volt. Anything more will be appreciated. Peter pls help..or shall take my laptop to Dell service center?